# How to limit the depth while using dijkstra algorithm in neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, dijkstra

I am applying dijkstra algorithm for traversal in neo4j, because I wanted the path with least cost from source to destination. Is it possible to get the cheapest path from source to destination having at max 'n' number of edges?
My current code is:

```
public static PathFinder<WeightedPath> dijkstraTraverser = GraphAlgoFactory.dijkstra(expander, "cost");
```

In normal traversal I can put an upper cap on the path length like this:

```
public static final TraversalDescription allTraverser = baseTraverser.evaluator( Evaluators.toDepth( 3 ) );
```

Is there any way to apply the same upper limit while traversing graph using dijkstra algorithm?

I am using neo4j v2.0

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a separate object that keeps track of some state, namely the sum total cost of a given path; i.e. in your evaluator you would need to compute the cost of a Path, and then return the correct evaluation.

Create an evaluator that stores the cheapest path seen; start it at an unrealistically high value; each time you encounter a path, update the cheapest cost you've seen, and return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE if the path is cheaper than the cheapest you've seen; otherwise return Evalution.EXCLUDE_AND_PRUNE

If you have some extra upper limit you wish to enforce, that's just one small extra condition in your evaluator;  if the total path cost is >= your limit, exclude and prune.

http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/Evaluator.html#evaluate%28org.neo4j.graphdb.Path%29